# How to find Dynamics 365 online svc end point to use Connected Service in Visual Studio.Net?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I am trying to use a connected service in visual Studio.net for Microsoft Dynamics 365 online. How to find the svc end-point url since I am  running the trial version?

I am trying to do POC via console app right now to fetch / create / update data.

I have the rest of the information like

- Page ODataV4  URL ,
- Query URL,
- Tenant key

I have done a POC for PAGE Url with `HttpWebRequest` but in this case I have to create my own DTOs and then serialize  JSON Results to DTO objects. So I want to use "Connected Service" but I can't find the svc endpoint.

Comment: Did you get a chance to verify my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Historically there were endpoints like `OrganizationMetadata.svc` retired. Soon `Organization.svc` will retire (deprecated now). So only endpoint for future is going to be RESTful web api.

Navigate to `Settings -> Customizations -> Developer Resources`, you will find the necessary urls.

[Read more](https://www.itaintboring.com/dynamics-crm/the-soap-endpoint-is-dying-long-live-the-organization-service/)

[image]